# Why is Angular stable in test environment when a setInterval is running

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

Let us start with this oversimplified component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  startInterval() {
    setInterval(() => { }, 1000);
  }
}
```

It contains a `startInterval` method, which just starts a plain interval. If the application is running and that method is not invoked, Angular is considered stable. I confirm this by the following script executed in the browser console:

```
window.getAllAngularTestabilities()[0].isStable(); // Returns true
```

If the interval has started, the same script returns `false`, which is what I expect - an interval is running, so Angular cannot be stable.

However, I cannot reproduce this in testing environment:

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should make Angular unstable when there are unfinished tasks', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    app.startInterval();
    expect(fixture.isStable()).toEqual(false); // Fails, Angular is stable
  });
});
```

I tried testing in `async` and in `fakeAsync` zones, but the result is still the same. I also tried to access the zone object from the fixture, but it doesn't seem to give the results I expect:

```
 console.log(fixture.ngZone.hasPendingMicrotasks); // Logs false
 console.log(fixture.ngZone.isStable); // Logs true
```

Why is Angular stability different in different environments? Is this a bug, or I'm missing something?

Comment: What if you use `fixture.detectChanges()` after `app.startInterval();` in your test?

Comment: Nothing changes, unfortunately. Angular is still stable.